# Mysql performance with low memory

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a serious performance issue with mysql on my server. I have a pretty big table, not specially by the number of rows (~900 000 rows) but more with the number of columns (~90 Columns) and with a lot of indexes (~30 indexes) (It's an Innodb table).

When i do a count(*) from the table after i didnt made any query for some time, the query can take a laaaaarge amount of time, here is a result of a show processlist :

```
| Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                      |
| Query   | 430  | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG where PUBLISH = 1 and (Exclusions = 2 or Exclusions is null) |
```

Almost 10mn to do a count(*), and when i try it without cache after that :

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG where PUBLISH = 1 and (Exclusions = 2 or Exclusions is null);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   900872 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.66 sec)
```

Or with cache :

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG where PUBLISH = 1 and (Exclusions = 2 or Exclusions is null);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   900872 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What mysql can do for 10mn on this table ? Maybe it's a lack of memory ? The swap is pretty much high on the server ...

Edit : here is the explain of the query

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG where PUBLISH = 1 and (Exclusions = 2 or Exclusions is null);
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CATALOG | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 905537 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)
```

Comment: count(*) uses every columns. What if you use COUNT(1) ?

Comment: ^ yeah be specific, and also maybe your index is not that good for your query. so instead of using the indexes it reverted to a full table scan.

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN for your count query to see which (if any) of the 30 indexes it might be using?

Comment: None indexes are used, maybe the query is not very optimised but it does not explains why sometimes it spends 10mn to do it, while it spend 0.66s to do it without cache.I added the explain.

Comment: I was wondering if mysql wasn't recalculating all the table indexes, i don't really know how the indexes works, i don't know if it's possible.

But it could explains why it spend 10mn, creating 30 indexes on a table like that should spend this amount of time.

Comment: You're I/O bound, that's all. You said it's a low memory server so your data doesn't fit into RAM. In order to perform the query, MySQL has to look into values. What indexes are for is to help MySQL find those values on disk faster (they often get into RAM if possible). Since you don't have much memory, and you depend on the speed of your disk - reason for this slowness is your hardware. There are techniques where people keep count values in another table, but you have varying conditions so this might not help. You'll need a faster I/O subsystem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was thinking it was indeed a memory problem. I will double the memory, and hope it will be enough.

Comment: You need to configure InnoDB to use available memory, I take it you're going to be able to find out how?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'CATALOG';`.

30 indexes is a lot.

```
INDEX(PUBLISH, Exclusions)
```

would be the optimal index for *this* query.  The `EXPLAIN` would say `Using index` instead of `Using where`.

Based on the `EXPLAIN`, it did a table scan; 0.66s is not bad.  The cached version is irrelevant; it found the query in the "Query cache" and returned the result without doing any real work.  InnoDB has its "buffer_pool", which seemed to contain the entire table, hence 0.66s, apparently without any I/O.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

"What mysql can do for 10mn on this table?" -- What are you asking; what is 'mn'?  MySQL can handle virtually any sized table.  Table scans take longer as the table gets bigger.  Once the table becomes bigger than the buffer_pool, a table scan will become I/O-bound, and this query will slow down significantly.  But it will (eventually) finish.  (I don't see "10 *minutes*" anywhere in your output.)

If you configure MySQL to use too much RAM, such that it "swaps", performance will become really, really, bad.  A one-liner rule:  the buffer_pool should be about 70% or available RAM.  Smaller is less efficient; larger threatens to swap.

What Engine is this table?  If it is MyISAM, then some other operation could have the table locked.  InnoDB is better, in general.

`COUNT(*)` is the normal way to say it; `COUNT(1)` gives you the same answer with the same effort.  `COUNT(col)` has the added burden of checking `col` for being `NULL`.

MySQL does not rebuild indexes unless you ask for it, via `ALTER` or `OPTIMIZE`.  Indexes are incrementally maintained.  With rare exceptions, they are always in nearly optimal format.

Without knowing what is causing the problem, doubling the memory may not be cost-effective.